# How to use Spring MVC with AngularJS ui-router?

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, angular-ui-router

How do I set up Spring MVC to catchAll requests and just return my welcome page (index.html)?

My overall intention is to use Spring MVC to intercept anything with "/api/" so that I can make calls to the backend, but any other url should return "index.html" so that ui-router can attempt to show the correct view.

However with my current setup I can navigate around the site using ui-router but when I attempt to navigate to a url that should be resolved by ui-router I get this error:

```
Problem accessing /app/hi/hello. Reason:
Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL 
[/app/hi/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result 
of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

My setup:

**BaseController.java**

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping("/app/**")
    public String get() {
       return "index.html";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatch-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.football_preds"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="dist/football-preds.js"></script>
  <title>Football Predictions</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <section ui-view></section>

  <button ui-sref="login">Login page</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it:

- Moved `index.html` into /views and renamed it `index.jsp`
- **My controller class:**

  ```
  @Controller
  public class BaseController {

      // Map all urls to this method aside from ones starting with api
      @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
      public String getIndex() {
          // return the view called "index.html" (in the current directory)
          return "index";
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/api/**")
      @ResponseBody
      public String testApi() {
          return "test string";
      }
  }
  ```

This, some how, manages to handle all requests that aren't prefixed with "/api" and return the index page which uses ui-router to handle urls.

Answer (score -1):

You getting it wrong.

Dispatch one server page only (index.jsp), Angular is SPA.

After that, its all RESTful API that Spring should provide to have Angulared Application.

ui-router is client site routing library.

```
public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");

        return model;
    }
}
```

this should return home.do or as you configured.

Comment: But how do I set up GAE/Spring to return index.jsp regardless of the url?

Comment: you can refer this tut http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/ also too have one server page to use.

Comment: then you can have"/api" in request mapping to distinguish api calls.

Comment: What will happen when some one hits the url example.com/category/restaurant? In this scenarios, expected behavior is server returns index.html. Ui rounter decided which API to call based on the url string.